# My Javascript classes are inheriting attributes from their prototype, but not functions! Why is this?

Tags: javascript

I have a base class here:

```
function Screen(src) {
this.src = src;
}

Screen.prototype.html = function(collapsed) {
    return $.ajax({
        async : false,
        url : this.src + "?collapsed=" + collapsed,
    }).responseText;
};
```

And then I try to subclass it:

```
function TitleScreen() {
    Screen.call(this, "title.php");
};
TitleScreen.prototype = Object.create(Screen.prototype);
TitleScreen.prototype.constructor = TitleScreen;
TitleScreen.prototype.parent = Screen.prototype;
```

However when I do so, and attempt to use a TitleScreen object, it has its src property set, but the html function is not defined! I also tried setting the html function in the constructor, like so:

```
function Screen(src) {
    this.src = src;
    this.html = function(collapsed) {
        return $.ajax({
            async : false,
            url : this.src + "?collapsed=" + collapsed,
        }).responseText;
    };
}
```

But that didn't work either. What am I doing wrong that could cause plain old attributes to work but not functions?

Comment: [Worksforme](http://jsfiddle.net/aftRP/). Please show us *how* you attempt to use a `TitleScreen` object

Comment: Do you really receive a `ReferenceError` when `new TitleScreen(someUrl).html();` is called? I tried this code and it works in my chrome.

Comment: try this: TitleScreen.prototype = Object.create( new Screen(), {} );

Comment: @philipp: No. Why should he do that???

Comment: Your code looks correct. Your `TitleScreen` instances should have a `.html()` method. How are you creating your instances?

Comment: just thought that this makes the .html() missing... inheritance is described like this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_Revisited

Comment: I have an array of Screen objects called screens, with a variable curScreen containing the index of the current screen, and I call it like so: $("#focus").html(screens[curScreen].html());

Comment: And by the way, I'm not getting a ReferenceError; I'm getting a TypeError: "Object #<Object> has no method 'html'"

Comment: Aha! new TitleScreen().html() returns some HTML, but the object I'm using says it's undefined, because I've JSON-serialized it and stuffed it into local storage!

Comment: Your code seems to be perfectly fine as demonstrated here: http://jsfiddle.net/RWJmK/

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget the `new` keyword? Only when you create an instance of the constructor function, the object will inherit from the `prototype` object:

```
var title = new TitleScreen();
"html" in title; // true
```

[Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/aftRP/1)

Or do you have some additional code which you didn't show to us that overwrites the `TitleScreen.prototype` instead of adding properties to it?

Comment: Thanks, but I did use new when instantiating the objects, and I don't think I've overwritten the prototype property!

Answer (score 0):

My issue was actually completely unrelated to inheritance; it had to do with local storage.

Calling new TitleScreen().html() did in fact return the HTML, but I was serializing the Screen objects as JSON and placing them in local storage so my app could remember its state. However the serialization apparently did not take into account the functions, so I was losing those.

To solve my problem I'll need to reconstitute the functions when I deserialize from local storage.